# How to get Latest Component changes on Component View through GUI Extension

Tags: gui-extensions

I have a Schema, it has a component link field. Whenever I insert a component , unable to find its reference in getContentSection method. I have Validation on the Save/SaveClose command

```
if (item) {
        $evt.removeEventHandler(item, "load", MyFunction);
        if (item.getItemType() == $const.ItemType.COMPONENT) {
            if (item.getSchema().getInfo().Title == "TestSchema") {
            if(item.getChanged()){
               console.log("getContentSection:"+item.getContentSection());
               console.log("getNewXmlDocument:"+$xml.getNewXmlDocument(item.getContentSection()));
               }
            }
            $evt.addEventHandler(item, "load", MyFunction);
            item.load();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Is it an optional field? In XML, optional fields with no values will not appear.

Comment: It has values, but unable to get the updated details. Is there a way of getting changes in component through SourceTab content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below Snippet gives me changes in Component on component View

```
var itemDisplayTest=$display.getItem();
itemDisplayTest.collectData();
itemDisplayTest.getContentSection();
```

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the contents of any type of container in the Content Manager you can use the **GetListItems()** method, which returns a DOM document, or the **GetItems()** method which returns a Collection of objects.

TOM.NET classes that use the **GetListItems()** and **GetItems()** methods
The following TOM.NET classes use the **GetListItems()** and **GetItems()** methods to filter lists of items contained in this type of container:

- Repository ( Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Repository)
- Publication (Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.Publication)
- Organizational Item (Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.OrganizationalItem), the   parent class of the following four classes
- Category (Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Category)
- Folder (
  Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Folder)
- Virtual Folder (
  Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.VirtualFolder)
- Structure
  Group (
  Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.StructureGroup)

**Parameters and return values**

Depending on the item type, both the **GetListItems()** and **GetItems()** methods take a parameter of either class RepositoryItemsFilter or OrganizationalItemItemsFilter, that lets you specify how the results of the method call are to be filtered:

- In a GetListItems() call, you can restrict the amount of information that is returned for each item (for example, only the ID and title of each item)
- In both methods, you can restrict which items are returned from the total set of items contained in the container (for example, only items that are Components)

The return value of each method is different:

- A call to GetListItems() returns an XML document that consists of one
  tcm:ListItems element containing zero or more tcm:Items elements.
- A call to GetItems() returns an IEnumerable of those objects in the container that match the filter criteria.

Please try this code.

```
var item = this.getItem();
var modifiedDate = item.getLastModifiedDate() || item.getStaticLastModifiedDate();
```

Comment: This may be correct, but Stack Exchange automatically flags a three-line answer as being of low quality. I suppose they have a point; I'm sure if you added some explanation it would be a better answer.

Comment: Hi Rao, I'm looking for changes done in component not modified date

Comment: please share full source code. after update code changes. you clear the browser cache and history?.

Comment: Yes I cleared cache and History, and tried in incogntio window too, above is the key code snippet